# using raw coordinate when drawing a tikz angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0.0, 0.0);
    \coordinate (ac) at (1.0, 1.0);
    \coordinate (bc) at (0.7, 0.1);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (ac);
    \draw[->] (O) -- (bc);
    \pic[draw, angle eccentricity=1.5]{angle=bc--O--ac};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When drawing the angle can I use bare coordinates? I try

```
\pic[draw, angle eccentricity=1.5]{angle=bc--(0.0, 0.0)--ac};
```

but it does not work.

Can I use bare coordinates when drawing a tikz angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not use direct coordinates.

From the manual page 570 about `Pic type angle=⟨A⟩--⟨B⟩--⟨C⟩` :

> The three points ⟨A⟩, ⟨B⟩, and ⟨C⟩ must be the names of nodes or
> coordinates; you cannot use direct coordinates like “(1,1)” here.